Implementation of arrays that store their size
In this code I implemented arrays that store their own size before the first element. To access it you need to go back exactly sizeof(size_t) bytes back. To free it, you free the pointer to this position. Did I do anything wrong about pointer manipulation? I'm not really experienced in C.
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define alloc_with_size(type, array, size)\
    type *array = malloc(sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(type) * size);\
    *(size_t *)array = size;\
    array = (type *)((char *)array + sizeof(size_t))

#define size_ptr(array) (size_t *)((char *)array - sizeof(size_t))
#define get_size(array) *size_ptr(array)
#define free_with_size(array) free(size_ptr(array))

#define foreachindex(index, array, code) for (size_t index = 0; index < get_size(array); i++) code
#define foreachitem(item, type, array, code) { type item; for (size_t _ = 0; _ < get_size(array); _++) { item = array[_]; code } }

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    alloc_with_size(int, bugger, 257);
    foreachindex(i, bugger, {
        bugger[i] = i;
    })
    foreachitem(item, int, bugger, {
        printf("%d\n", item);
    })
    free_with_size(bugger);
}


I would move the include for stdio.h to live with the other includes.

If I were to move the macros to a header file, I wouldn't need the stdio.h, it's only used in the tests.

If there's anything you don't want comments on (e.g. the #include of stdio.h) then don't include it in the code you're asking for comments on. If you know that line should be at the top in real code with the rest of the content you show then put it at the top in your sample code. Please [edit] your question to show the code you do want our feedback on.

Why did you call the variable bugger?  Do you mean to be offensive, or is that accidental?

@TobySpeight, typo, supposed to be buffer, obviously, but as the answers now include this spelling, I won't change it

Bug: It does not certainly work per the C spec.
Code failed to maintain alignment requirements for type.

array = (type *)((char *)array + sizeof(size_t)) is a problem.
It assumes (type *)((char *)array + sizeof(size_t)) is a valid pointer for type.
array is an OK pointer for a type * as malloc() returns a pointer aligned for any standard type.  (char *)array + sizeof(size_t) may lack that alignment requirement.
Example: type needed an alignment of 8, yet sizeof(size_t) was only 4 bytes.
The issue is that the allocation needs to be sizeof (size_t) + potential_padding + sizeof(type) + size.  OP's code is missing the potential padding.
typedef struct data {
  size_t size;  // maybe padding after .size
  type x[];
}

void *array = malloc(sizeof(struct data) + sizeof(type) * size) would allocate enough, including the potential padding.  See  flexible array member.
And then the calling code would use bugger = (type *) &((struct data *)array + 1);
For me, I would use the type below to handle all allocations.  This way, when freeing, the type is not needed.  We just assume the worst case.
#includse <stddef.h>

typedef struct data {
  size_t size;
  max_align_t x[]; // object type whose alignment is the greatest fundamental alignment;
}


The moral of the story, the resultant pointer for the calling code (bugger in this case) needs to be of the proper alignment.

I didn't understand the data struct, then tested it and I think I now get it. So, adding an empty array of max_align_t aligns the structure with the max alignment, even though it's empty?

@yurich Yes.  Review flexible array member.

Once you have a proper struct, I think it's better for the client code to use .size and .x directly, rather than dense expressions such as (type *) &((struct data *)array + 1).

@TobySpeight How about (type *) array->x?  Do not see a need for .size.

OP sees a need for the size member - that's what the get_size() macro accesses.

@TobySpeight Yes, .size is needed in struct data, but not for the return address computation.
I'll rephrase. "Do not see a need for .size" for forming an alternative to (type *) &((struct data *)array + 1).  (type *) array->x is sufficient.

Oh, absolutely - I just believe that making the struct public is better than obscuring it with all these macros.  And the cast is unnecessary when x is a type[].  You might want to mention offsetof() for the computation back to the start address.

@TobySpeight "cast is unnecessary when x is a type[]" --> True, yet max_align_t x[]; is better as it makes the computation back to the start address easy: original_pointer = (struct data *)user_pointer_to_free)[-1].

Yes, it works, BUT... it violates convention, and I wouldn't want this in a project I was responsible for.
Your data structure contains a pointer, but hands back e.g., an "int[]". This violates the expectations of anyone who has worked in C, and will cause problems if this is project maintained by multiple people. To be honest, I would predict bugs even if only one programmer used it, if they mix real C arrays with your arrays (i.e. if they use the standard C library!). You are at some point going to confuse the two types.
The problem is that if I have an array of newly-allocated int[] returned to me by a function, I own it, must free it, and I do this all the time as a C programmer. When I'm done, I (a) call free(), or (b) pass it to a function which processes the array and frees it or (c) return it to a caller, who then owns the memory.
All of these are serious problems. (a) or (b) directly cause intermittent, lethal bugs. Not necessarily during my testing! Might even work for most customers. If it doesn't work for somebody, I might not be able to reproduce their bug. There are estimates that C programmers spend about half of their time dealing with memory bugs; please don't make it easier to create bugs.
(c) Requires documentation. Documentation is often not written (no comments in your sample code!), not read, and not kept updated. Sometimes not understood even if it is written, updated, and read. Frequently not remembered later.
FIX:
Make it a struct with a pointer to the array. The struct contains a C array, which we can treat like any C array. You could either make it a const pointer and the compiler will prevent users from resizing the array, or provide a function to resize the array. The first prevents some usages of this where a malloc'd array would work; the second is a source of bugs when people reallocate it themselves and forget to change the size.
As per [@chux - Reinstate Monica]'s answer, we must be careful of alignment --- see their example struct with "max_align_t".
NOT A FIX: A typedef won't fix this, because I can still assign it to int[] and pass it as an int[].
Background:
Because C lacks much of the encapsulation of other languages, C programmers spend much of their time manipulating details of data structures which would "manage themselves" in an object-oriented language. A very important example of this is having to allocate and free memory, and to keep track of which memory my code "owns". For most (simple) objects I just free() them when returned from other functions. Arrays and structs are the simple objects I routinely receive as a C programmer and, if I own them, I KNOW I must free them. With structs I understand that I'm responsible for the contents. With arrays, I have no worries!
SUGGESTED IMPROVEMENTS:
The size macro/function should just return a size_t, not a pointer to the size. You don't want anyone to accidentally change it.
You should add read and write macros that check the size, so you get the full benefits of this new data type! Just understand that most people won't use them. You can encourage use by having a version with a boolean flag, "checked" (or play tricks in the header file), so people can turn off the checks with a #define.

Why do you think it hands back int[]? It uses malloc which returns int * and adds sizeof(size_t) and them converts back to int *.

"The size macro/function should just return a size_t, not a pointer to the size" - I dont get your point here. There are 2 macros for size: size_ptr and get_size. The last one returns value, not a pointer. And about changing the value - you're probably right, but I could just undef the macro after I've declared everything else that depends on it

Oh, I thing I get the thing - someone could do this: get_size(array)++, which would, indeed change the size.

@yurich If the compiler accepts int[], then in C there's no difference from *int, it's just syntactic sugar, an indication of how the coder is thinking of the access. You are correct in that there are places (allocations!) where the compiler won't accept int[] instead of int*, but I chose int[] because it looks like you are trying to create an array type, and presumably intend to access this *int foo with statements like foo[13] = 5.

You have omitted some very important code between these two lines:

type *array = malloc(sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(type) * size);\
*(size_t *)array = size;\


Whenever malloc() returns a null pointer, accessing *array (with or without the cast) is Undefined Behaviour.

I recommend using all-caps for macro identifiers, rather than lower-case.  It's important for users to be aware that they are writing lexical substitutions rather than function calls - particularly when arguments are expanded more than once.

Overall, I don't like this style of hiding a data object somewhere unexpected - it's unintuitive and unusual, and not visible to interactive debuggers.
I think it would be clearer to define a simple struct ending in a flexible array member, as well as a few functions to work with that (alloc, free, etc.).  You could use a macro to generate the definitions of the structure and functions if you find you need collections of many different types.

How should I handle that scenario in this case?

That's something you should apply some thought to - most likely, you'll want to return a null pointer in that circumstance, and client code should be warned that that's a possible outcome.  You should probably also handle being passed a null pointer in the free_with_size() macro, as Standard Library free() does.
